It might be a pigeon hole but I’m not sure

There is a group of people and in the group, $55.5 \%$ are males. (Correct to first decimal place)
Find the minimum number of the male.
For example, $111/200=55.5 \%$ $\qquad \qquad$ But how to make sure there doesn’t exist any number which is lower than $200$ that can makes the answer $55.45 \%$to $55.5 \%$ correct?

OK, here is what I have tried.
Let $a, b$ $\in$ $\Bbb N$ and are relatively primes.
$0.5545 <a/b <0.5555$
$110.9 < 200/b < 111.1$
And then I have no idea.
Or maybe it’s not a pigeonhole problem?

Brute force works easily enough... don't know the context and whether you are strictly looking for pen&paper approaches... but $61/110 = 0.554545\dots$, $66/119=0.5546218\dots$, $71/128=0.5546875$, $76/137=0.5547445\dots$ and so on

You can avoid brute force by using continued fractions

$0.5545 = [0; 1,1,4,11,2,9]$ and $0.5555 = [0; 1,1,4,222]$, so the fraction in between with the smallest denominator is $[0; 1,1,4,12] = 61/110 = 0.554545\dots$

Continue fraction is right!! I try to understand it by ChatGPTAnd it seems to be the right way to solve it!!! You are genius ❤️thanks! Originally I thought it’s pigeon hole… so it took me a century to solve this…

"I try to understand it by ChatGPT"  ChatGPT does not understand math or science and will confidently say incorrect things.  It is not to be used for things like this.

@JMoravitz I was at a conference a few days ago, and a speaker said, ChatGPT is not a scientist, it's more like an MBA - it's answers may not be correct, but they will definitely be quick and confident!
